# retrieving string values from another class

Tags: ios, string, swift

I am trying to use manipulated strings from a separate class in my ViewController. To keep things simple, let's say I have a `String` in `Other.class` that I'm changing using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`. I then set this value to a `String` in my `ViewController`.

```
var name: String!
name = "John"

...

func changeString {
    name = name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("a", withString: "e")
}

self.mainViewController!.fakeName = name
```

In my `ViewController`, I then use that string as a value for a table cell like so:

```
var fakeName: String?
...
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.nameLabel.text = fakeName!
        }
```

For some reason, `fakeName` keeps returning a nil value and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

I'm a Java developer who's new to Swift, so I'm just getting used to the syntax. Apologies if this question has a really obvious answer.

Comment: What's your question? What part is not working?

Comment: use push segue in viewcontroller

Comment: fakeNamereturns is a nil value in my view controller. Sorry, I'll edit the post to clarify that.

Comment: u know push segue in swift?

Comment: Do you ever initialize `name`? It's implicitly unwrapped but you don't show how an instance of `String` is assigned to it.

Comment: @KennethBruno Yes, I did. Sorry, should have added that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is working for you. Declare variable out side from class For Example. Other things You have create one .swift file and declare variable as Global variable.

```
var fakeName : String = ""
// First Class where you change the value of name
class ViewController : UIViewController 
{
     func changeString {
    name = name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("a", withString: "e")
}
}

// Other Class where you use the value of name
class mainViewController : UIViewController 
{
   ......
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.nameLabel.text = fakeName 
        }
}
```

//As Per Your question you have to allocate your variable not just decleare only

```
var fakeName: String = ""
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be allocated immediately if it's an `Optional`, it can be set at a later time.

Comment: This answered my question, but the actual problem was that I forgot to call `self.table.reloadData()`. Thank you for your trouble! :)